# Database design: Multiple non-identifying relationships between two tables

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I'm new to database design and have some uncertainties about how best to model this particular case. I'd appreciate any suggestions for this fairly simple scenario.

When a production task begins, two people are involved at all times. One is in charge of the production, and a second is tasked with quality assurance. For any task in the database, it must be possible to identify these two people. They'll both exist in a Person table and have IDs, so I just want the best way to relate them to the production task. The following rules exist:

- Either person may be swapped out for a different person at any time.
- Each task always involves both people (Neither of these are null).
- There are never any other people involved in the task that we want to record.
- Each person may be involved in multiple tasks, or none at all.

If we had a whole host of relationships between the task and the people, I'd create some sort of convoluted relationship structure describing their relationship (As producer, quality assurance person, overseer, etc.), but here I feel as though it's sensible to just stick the IDs of the two people in the Task table, in separate columns for Production Person and Quality Assurance Person. Is this bad for some reason that I can't see?

What has really prompted my question is that I'm trying to design exactly that in DBDesigner 4, which I'm new to, and it just doesn't like it - When I try to set up a second non-identifying relationship between Task and Person, it won't give me a second field. It also won't seem to let me rename the fields in Task that refer to the persons, so it'd be impossible to differentiate between the two anyway. Since no-one else seems to share this problem, I've began to wonder whether it's a good idea at all. Is it standard to introduce additional tables as soon as there are two or more links between two entities? What would that look like if I wanted to enforce the above rules? I can't see how I'd ensure that an n:m table always has entries for both people working on the task.

Comment: There is another site in the Stack Exchange where this kind of question is more common and encouraged: [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com). SO encourages more specific, code related questions than design ones. I'm not downvoting or anything, just suggesting you try asking there.

Comment: @Renan Except, isn't cross-posting frowned on?

Comment: @ErikE IMO the best solution would be moving the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are confident your requirements will stay this rigid forever, then just create two NOT NULL FKs:

[image]

This declaratively enforces that **exactly** two people are associated to the task at all times, which would not be readily achievable with just the junction table (as you already noted).

OTOH, if you anticipate your requirements might change at some point in the future, then the added flexibility of junction table might be more important than the completely declarative enforcement of your business rules.

---

I'm not familiar with DBDesigner, and therefore with your particular problem, but in ER modeling in general, multiple relationships with the same entity are distinguished by their "rolenames" which determine the names of migrated attributes (see the section on "Rolenames" in the chapter 3 of the [ERwin Methods Guide](http://tangra.si.umich.edu/~radev/654/resources/ERMGALL.PDF)). Try locating something along those lines in the UI of your tool.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the current state and not who held the role previously @Branko Dimitrijevic's solution will work.

But if the statement 'Either person may be swapped out for a different person at any time' implies you need to know who previously held that role consider a 3 table design

```
Task; TaskID, <other details>

Assignee; TaskID, PeopleID, role, start_date, end_date

People; PeopleID, <other details>
```

Then in the assignee table you need constraints to ensure that for each TaskID, Role combination the dates are reasonable e.g. dates don't overlap or have gaps.  That you have only 1 of each role active for each task at a time.  To manage this would probably require code either in triggers or the application.